# How to get COUNT for same table in different databases with table name in SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a full export of 11 tables using Spark SQL from one database (DB1) to another database (DB2). Once the export is completed, I am comparing the count of each table on both DB1 and DB2 with table names and check they count matches (or) not. The output columns should be,

```
Table_name   DB1_count   DB2_count   Match (Y/N) ?
table_1         500         500           Y
table_2         376         325           N
```

So far, I have been able to fetch the columns 2 & 3 for one table. However, I'm not sure how to implement same for multiple tables and with the columns 1 & 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the two tables:

```
t1:

DB1_count   DB2_count
500         500
```

and

```
t2:

DB1_count   DB2_count
376         325
```

You can add the table name column and the match column, and do a union:

```
select 'table_1' as Table_name,
       DB1_count, DB2_count,
       case when DB1_count = DB2_count then Y else N end as Match
from t1
union all
select 'table_2' as Table_name,
       DB1_count, DB2_count,
       case when DB1_count = DB2_count then Y else N end as Match
from t2
```

To generate the query dynamically, you can try:

```scala
val names = Seq(("table_1", "t1"), ("table_2", "t2"))
val query = names.map(x => s"""
select '${x._1}' as Table_name,
       DB1_count, DB2_count,
       case when DB1_count = DB2_count then Y else N end as Match
from ${x._2}
""").mkString("\nunion_all\n")

val result = spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: It worked !! Thanks a lot for your help !! Any idea how the same can be achieved for multiple tables by passing the table names dynamically ?

Comment: You can use Python/Scala to generate the queries dynamically.

Comment: No but it'll be really helpful if you could please share it.

Comment: Thanks @mck but I am using scala. Is there a way the same can be achieved via scala ? Really thanks for your help !!

Comment: @Shyam does the edited answer work for you?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet (caught up with other work). I will definitely try this and confirm. Thanks again for your help and quick response on this.